# ruby 1.8.6 - build a zero-length space char from unicode values

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, ruby-1.8.6

In a ruby 1.8.6 (please don't tell me to upgrade it) app, i have a problem character in some text which is being imported, and i want to strip it out.

If I look at the byte values of the character i get this:

```
(0..3).collect{|n| char[n]}
=> [226, 128, 139, nil]
```

So, in order to filter it out, I **could** break every character down into its byte values and see if it matches the above, but that seems quite cumbersome.  It would be nicer if I could just do a `gsub` on the text, but i'm struggling to create the first argument to `gsub`, the string to replace.

I thought I would be able to build it from the above values, like so, but i get the wrong character:

```
>> zero_space = [226, 128, 139].pack('U*')
=> "â€‹"
```

How can I actually define this string/char in variable so that I can use it in a gsub?

Comment: What Unicode character do the bytes represent?

Comment: Is this a typo that you have `[116, ...` at the top and `[226,...` at the bottom of your question?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek good catch! With 226 it is U+200B, i.e. zero width space.

Comment: `zero_space = "\xE2\x80\x8B"` should work

Comment: @Stefan yes that was a typo thanks - it should have been 226.  I'll edit - that suggestion worked too, thanks!

Comment: [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'\u200B'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` yields `'â€‹'` where `'\u200B'` is U+200B,  *Zero Width Space*, see `'â€‹'.encode( 'cp1252').decode('utf-8')` ==> `'\u200b'`

Comment: @MaxWilliams FYI strings in Ruby 1.8 are just a sequence of bytes. You have to handle unicode characters via their byte representation.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Do you want to delete the question as it was just a typo or do you think it has some value to keep it up?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek the typo wasn't the source of the problem, it was just in my description of it.  I think it's a potentially useful question about constructing a unicode character.